# Multiple Axios calls in same file

Tags: reactjs, axios

Using React and Axios how can I put all of the Axios API calls (Get, Post, Delete...) in one .js file and call them based on the action I need? I currently have the following and I'm sure there is a better way. How can I have them in one person.js file and call the specific API call that I need at the time?

GetPerson.js

```
const getPerson = async (values) => {
    try{
     get Axios call
}catch{}

export default getPerson;
```

UpdatePerson.js

```
const updatePerson= async (values) => {
        try{
         put Axios call
    }catch{}

    export default updatePerson;
```

DeletePerson.js

```
const deletePerson= async (values) => {
        try{
         delete Axios call
    }catch{}

    export default deletePerson;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used, but from what I can tell, it works very muh like the fetch api.

Faced with a similar issue, I have a functions.js with a "retrieve" method that takes an URL, a verb (GET, POST, etc as string), headers and body.

import that function whenever you want to retrieve something from the server. However I dont see anything wrong with the way you are doing it right now.

```
export async function retrieve (endpoint, method, headers, body, successMessage) {
  console.log('Retrieving...\nAP:', endpoint, '\nMethod:', method, '\nHeaders:', headers, '\nBody:', body)
  try {
    const fetchOptions = {
      method: method || 'GET',
      headers: headers || new Headers(),
      body: method !== 'GET' && body ? body : null
    }
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, fetchOptions)
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error('Error retrieving data', response)
      throw new Error('Error retrieving data', response)
    }
    // get the data
    const data = await response.json()
    const camelizedData = camelizeKeys(data)
    if (successMessage) console.log(`${successMessage}\n`, camelizedData)
    // return the resolved promise
    return Promise.resolve(camelizedData)
  } catch (error) {
    // return the rejected promise with the error message
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}
```

In this example I am using humps' "camelizeKeys" method to change the snake_case response from the server. Which was primarily the reason for using a single method for all my api calls.